# How to set picture position using VBA in MS-Word?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have a access database which has tables and forms. I have a submit button in access form. When I clicked this button, I'm creating a ms word document. I have image paths in my database table and I'm putting images in my word document. I wrote this codes to put images in word document.

```
Set objDOCRange = objDOC.Content

With objDOC
    Dim objDocPicApproved As Word.InlineShape
    Set objDocPicApproved = objDOC.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imgPath_approved, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    objDocPicApproved.PictureFormat.Application.Left = -10
    objDocPicApproved.PictureFormat.Application.Top = -100
    objDocPicApproved.ScaleHeight = 120
    objDocPicApproved.ScaleWidth = 180
    Dim objDocPic As Word.InlineShape
    Set objDocPic = objDOC.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imgPath_rp, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    objDocPic.ScaleHeight = 120
    objDocPic.ScaleWidth = 180
End With
```

Everything is OK until now. I want to position them where the second arrow is located instead of the first arrow. But I don't know how to do it?

[image]

I'm using word document template to do tables and other things. I'm replacing fields using **DOCVARIABLES** then I'm doing save as.

Comment: Top and Left should define where the images go. X and Y = zero a the top left of the page, and you've set the top and left to -100 and -10 respectively. Try larger numbers for Top eg. 500

Comment: @RowanC I solve the problem. I changed `Word.InlineShape` to `Word.Shape`